# Curiosity about namespace and function parameters

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

**one.h:**

```
namespace one {
    class X : public IZ {
        public:
            void function(); // virtual function (=0) in IZ
    }
}
```

**two.h**

```
namespace one {
    class Y {
        public:
            void functionY(class X& x); // or one::X& x
    }
}
```

I have several classes distributed by several files, all sharing the same namespace. From what I've understood, if I have the same namespace for all classes, they all can access each other without the need to put NAMESPACE::class_x since they all belong to the same namespace.

What I'd like to understand is why in the special case above described there's the need to use the keyword `class` or `namespace::` before `X& x`.

Is it related to `X` inheritance of `IZ` which as a virtual function then "overwritten" in `X`?

Comment: Have you forward declared `class X` in two.h?

Comment: @Cornstalks that doesn't work, I need to include the class X header file and use the class X keyword, or else I get a "you need to use class tag in this scope something". But it's weird since other classes don't give out that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question: the problem was caused by circular referencing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the X type is resolved in compile time. The linker needs to understand what X is and it is a class or it is scoped in a namespace.

1. If you scope it to be in the same namespace `namespace::x` then you
   would get a compile error if the class is not defined in the
   namespace.
2. If you define it to be a class and the same class exists in the
   namespace the definition belongs to, then that definition would be
   resolved.

Comment: But I have another class, lets call it W, that is also used in a Y class function, and that one doesn't give me an error if I don't put class W or one::W. They all belong to the same namespace. Can it be related to having one.h included in two.h and two.h in one.h?

Comment: @lm2s I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Namespace or not, you need to *declare* a class which you want to refer to later.

You can either `#include "one.h"` in your file two.h to make the entire definition of `one::X` known, or you can just add a declare `X` without defining it:

```
// two.h

namespace one
{
    class X;

    class Y
    {
        void f(X const & x);
        // ...
    };
}
```

In either case, you *don't* need to restate the namespace since you're already inside it.

Comment: Just forwarding the class doesn't work, I need to include the header. It might be related to cross includes…

Comment: @lm2s: It depends on whether you need the complete type of `X` or not. Only you can know that. The example I posted is correct, but probably not representative of your actual code.

Comment: The actual problem seems to be about circular referencing, and since X is a singleton class I need full access and class forwarding doesn't work. Thank you for your help! :)